# Landauer's formula with non-reciprocal tunneling probability

Tags: quantum-tunneling, mesoscopic-physics

The Landauer's formula for ballistic transport in a mesoscopic conductor is often derived by assuming the transmission probability of the channel follows reciprocity symmetry, i.e.

$I \propto \int M(E) T_0(E) \left[f_L(E) - f_R(E)\right] dE$,

where $E$ is the electron energy, $M(E)$ is the number of mode in the channel, $f_L$ and $f_R$ are the Fermi-Dirac distribution in the left and right electron reservoirs, respectively, and the tunneling probability is assumed to be the same for electron tunneling from left-lead to right-lead and that from right-lead to left-lead, i.e.

$
T_L(E) = T_R(E) = T_0(E)
$.

For non-reciprocal tunneling, i.e. $T_R(E) \neq T_L(E)$, I attempt to generalize the Landauer's formula as followed:

$
I \propto \int M(E) \left[ T_L(E) f_L(E) - T_R(E) f_R(E) \right]
$.

The above relation however doesn't seem right. If I consider the two leads has identical distribution function, $f_L(E) = f_R(E) =f_0(E)$, i.e. both of the leads are unbiased and isothermal, then the generalized Landauer's relation yields:

$
I \propto \int M(E)f_0(E) \left[ T_L(E) - T_R(E) \right] \neq 0
$.

This is a particularly bizzare results since it indicates that current can flow in the absence of any biasing force! Have I done anything wrong in deriving the above "generalized Landauer formula"?

Many thanks.